# Twitter script not working in div

Tags: css, html, twitter

IM very new to html/css etc. and Im trying to nest a twitter feed into a div but I just cant get it to appear in the div container

```
<div id="leftmaincontainer"> <m3>Up and Coming Gigs</m3> <br />
<br />
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#eb0707'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('The_Buzz_band').start();
</script> <m4>Giggy gigs</m4> </div>
```

Comment: @wnajar is right, this does sit inside the div container.

Answer (score 0):

Your div **IS** inside the div container. You can verify this using a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LQH8E/

I've used the exact same code you pasted.

To make it easier to see, I've made the background of the div `blue` so you can see what it encompasses.

Maybe you were looking to do something with this div, perhaps style it, center it or something else and didn't realize that you actually had all the content in the div?

I've done a little styled example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/LQH8E/1/ using the same HTML that you provided.

Comment: I see what your doing is right but however I form it I just get [link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-kQAYWtOpJOM/T71Q-9WyGeI/AAAAAAAAAAs/jwydk5C-QPc/s800/stage2.png)

Comment: @user1413530 It looks like you have a lot of other things going on there. You could have closed the `div` earlier somewhere mistakenly, etc. etc. a million things. If you want, you can post your entire webpage and we can see what the problem is, but for this isolated issue here the code is correct and the div should be contained. Perhaps you can try to simplify things down on your website and attempt to make your code reflect what I've written, which works in the jsFiddle and anywhere else.

Comment: I cant paste it at the moment because my reps to low but iv tried the same code straight into a body of a page and it didnt work so i guess it means either bluegriffin is crap, firefox is crap or my css for the body is crap.. im betting the later                      body
{
 width:800;
 height:auto;
 background-color:#333333;
 height:1%;
 overflow:scroll;
 padding:10px 0;

}

Comment: You probably have other CSS rules that are confounding the problem. The editor used shouldn't make a difference, and here neither should the browser. You can verify that this works as written again here: http://pastehtml.com/view/bz2pftez4.html

You need to make sure the HTML **AND CSS** are pasted, not just the HTML. I didn't change your HTML at all, only wrote CSS rules.

**Edit:** I'm wondering if you forgot to paste the CSS in your css stylesheet....

Comment: You've forgotten these rules that I wrote, which make **ALL** the difference -_-:

`#leftmaincontainer{font: 10pt/1.35 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background:#ccc;width:250px;margin:15px auto;padding:15px;}
m3{font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;}
m4{font-size:16px;}`

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I think Im just bad at web design thanks alot for the help though il keep at it